# Current data / Date range in script fields using Kibana 4

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

I'm trying to generate a script field in Kibana 4 and I need to compute the difference between a date field and the current date:

(current_date - doc['startDate'].value)

I would also like to know if there is a way I could use the date range (from-to) of every kibana query in the script field. ex:

(to_date - doc['startDate'].value)

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: IIRC, kibana scripting only works on integers, and dates aren't truly integers.

Comment: I had no problems subtracting two existing date fields in a document. ex: (doc['endDate'].value - doc['startDate'].value). Computes the difference in milliseconds.